# How to get string between 2 characters using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a string with multiple comma delimiters.

For example `Test,User,Data,List`

I need to pull the data between the delimiters into a variable, what's the best way to accomplish this in a single command. The application I'm using allows for using VBScript, but I can't do this using multiple lines, just a single nested command.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Use `Split(...)` to put your data into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this is what you're after?

```
splitString = Split("Test,User,Data,List", ",")
```

Comment: I ended up using `Split` even though I was trying to parse it into a string, not an array. I thought that the application I was using wouldn't let me use the Array type, but it did, so thank you for your input.